# API Change Alert Information

Tags: google-drive-api

When changes are imminent to the API version, are admins/devs notified in advance via email or some other system?

Some companies I have found use twitter, hitch, or nothing at all to notify users of changes that may be deprecated. My goal is for us to stay on top of API changes so we never experience breakage.

Comment: Was my answer helpful/informative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is the case. When Google makes changes to the Drive API (and to others), most of the time it is written on the [Relase Notes](https://developers.google.com/drive/release-notes).

There is also the [Migration Page Guide](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/migration) where Google lists what's new and what's deprecated. Google also writes in red letters the outdated functionalities in their guides. Another way is they update devs is to announce it during conferences like Google I/O.

And lastly, the [support page](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/support) tells us devs to post questions here on Stackoverflow.